# What to call a doctor who doesn't really cure their patient with their effort (to get more money from "repeat business")?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, medical

[Doctors Are Not “Only Out to Make Money”](https://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/doctors-are-not-only-out-to-make-money/)

I read that article and can't get a good word for that kind of doctors, except the term *doctors (who) are only out to make money* in the second line of the third paragraph (I add the *who*). I would like to have a good concise term for this kind of doctors.

> There’s an old joke about the doctor whose son graduates from medical school and joins his practice. After a while the son tells his father, “You know old Mrs. Jones? You’ve been treating her rash for years and she never got better. I prescribed a new steroid cream and her rash is gone!” The father responds, “You idiot! That rash put you through medical school.”

Comment: Some just call it "business."

Comment: The closest is "charlatan", but it's not exactly what you're implying.

Comment: You're looking for a term that means "this doctor is in it for the money, not because he or she feels a calling to cure the ill"?

Comment: @Tim: I think the OP has been quite clear. He's not asking about a generic "in pursuit of money" motivation, but specifically the context where  someone ensures for themselves an ongoing income by merely *appearing* to provide a product/service (which doesn't actually *permanently* satisfy the customer's requirement, so said customer keeps repeatedly paying for some kind of "temporary fix"). The kind of thing various types of con-men do, not just dodgy doctors.

Comment: @Oldbag maybe *charlatan doctor*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers do you know any similar term but in economy? It can apply in here

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, but a requirement for this is that the "helper" be able to **profit** from "helping". (A bonus is being able to fake helping, or even to hurt, so that the patient does not get better and continues to need help.) It applies to any "helpers" or "repair" persons (e.g. car mechanic), but **only** if in such a profiting context. A doctor who is a salaried employee of a non-profit hospital, for example, is a priori less in this situation than a self-employed doctor who is remunerated by selling "help".

Comment: The article also suggests: **shills for Big Pharma**; **mercenary**; **greedy doctors**; and one commenter calls these types of doctors **quacks**.

Comment: @Mari-LouA nice catch. You can make this as an answer

Comment: Let someone else go, I only looked at the article, maybe there is a more accurate or pejorative term.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Shyster**

> a slang word for someone who acts in a disreputable, unethical, or unscrupulous way, especially in the practice of law, sometimes also politics or business.

http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Shyster

Answer (score 3):

If you LITERALLY mean the doctor (or perhaps, car mechanic) DELIBERATELY does not cure the patient, so that the patient will come back - so, exactly as in the joke stated.

The only thing I can really think of there is that the doctor would ***draw out*** the treatment, or perhaps someone like a car mechanic would ***string along*** a customer. In both cases they are ***milking it*** for all it is worth.

General terms like mercenary, bastard, charlatan, etc could mean many things. None of those specifically mean anything like *"deliberately giving a lesser treatment than would be ideal, so as to extend the customer's payments over time"*.

The only phrases I can think of are the three mentioned above.

(It makes me think of Ralph Nader and *planned obsolescence*. Perhaps Nader had a word for this?! Like "under-servicing" perhaps.)

Comment: I like the word *milking*, but it is the action of the doctors, not the term describing them.

Comment: I would forget about trying to not only find a phrase but a specific grammar-type-phrase for such an obscure SWR

Answer (score 2):

A sham doctor is called a "quack."

A very profit-driven quack is sometimes called a "snake-oil salesman," after men in the 1800s (roughly) who travelled around (often with a small circus, or "medicine show") peddling phony miracle cures allegedly made from ingredients like snake oil. That's probably the wrong connotation, though, since a snake-oil salesman didn't string along a small number of customers for a long time; he just sold as much snake oil as he could and then skedaddled before they caught on.

Comment: *Quack* is for who dishonestly claim that they have the knowledge which they don't. This is not what I'm really looking for since this kind of doctors actually graduate from med schools

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful!

Comment: +1 for 'Snake Oil Salesman'. I think that's getting closer to OP's meaning, but not quite there - best answer yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is "negligent" or "intentionally negligent":

> negligent:
>   failing to take proper or normal care of something or someone
>   failing to exercise the care expected of a reasonably prudent person in like circumstances

"Negligent" alone have connotations of carelessnes rather than doing it on purpose to take advantage the patient.  By adding "intentionally" (or "deliberately"), it is made clear that this is not just carelessness.

If you want in a shape where it can be used as a noun, I would suggest: "an intentionally negligent doctor" - but that is three words, not one.

Comment: I want a noun. How about *negligenter*?

Comment: AFAIK, "negligenter" is not an English word :-( .

Answer (score 1):

It's not specific to doctors, but I believe an appropriate term for the situation you describe is "parasite" as per definition 2a of the term at [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parasite):

> One who habitually takes advantage of the generosity of others without making any useful return.

Alternatives: **vampire**, **blood-sucker** and **leech**.

Comment: in a way, this is the only answer that really approaches the extremely-specific sense the OP has here.